# Create mask from vector of point

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

What is the best way (performance point of view) to create a boolean mask `cv::Mat` from `std::vector` of `cv::Point`? In other words, I want a full black `cv::Mat` with white pixels for the points that are exist in some `std::vector`. Something like:

```
std::vector<cv::Point> points;
//Filling points
cv::Mat mask(100, 100, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(0));
for (const auto& pnt: points){
    mask.ptr<uchar>(pnt.y)[pnt.x] = 255;
}
```

Is there a better(faster) approach? built-in one for example?

Comment: Unless your points are _contour_ points or polygon vertices, so that you can use `drawContours`, `polylines` or the like, I think that your approach is the only possible. If you have a lot of points compared to the mask area, probably sorting points and set pixels on the same row could give you a little speedup (but you need to sort the points).